# При наведении или нажатии на один из TextBox ов работает лишь первый остальные не хотят работать

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Узнайте_свой_разряд.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Узнайте_свой_разряд"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" Margin="0 0 0 0" MaxHeight="20" MaxWidth="68">Ваш пол</TextBlock>
            <ComboBox x:Name="Pol" MaxHeight="30" MaxWidth="80">
                <ComboBoxItem>Муж</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Жен</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" MaxHeight="20" MaxWidth="55">Cтиль</TextBlock>
            <ComboBox x:Name="Style" MaxHeight="30" MaxWidth="80">
                <ComboBoxItem>Кроль</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Брасс</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Спина</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Баттерфляй</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Комплекс</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Margin="120 145 0 0">Мил.сек</TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="MilSec" MaxHeight="20" MaxWidth="30" Margin="0 90 0 0"></TextBox>
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Margin="140 125 0 0">Сек</TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="Secunde" MaxHeight="20" MaxWidth="30" Margin="0 45 0 0"></TextBox>
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="13" Margin="140 104 0 0">Мин</TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="Minute" MaxHeight="20" MaxWidth="30" Margin="0 0 0 0"></TextBox>
        <Button MaxHeight="20" MaxWidth="60" Content="Узнать" Margin="0 150 0 0" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Это XAML

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int MiliSec = Convert.ToInt32(MilSec.Text);
            int Seconds = Convert.ToInt32(Secunde.Text);
            int Minuts = Convert.ToInt32(Minute.Text);
            if (((Pol.Text == "Муж") & (Style.Text == "Кроль")) & (Minuts == 0) & (Seconds == 25) & (MiliSec == 0))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Мастер спорта");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Это C#

Comment: `работает лишь первый остальные не хотят работать` - что это означает? И зачем вы налепили все  контролы друг на друга?

Comment: Добавил пример верстки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ваши TextBox'ы перекрыты TextBlock'ами. Пишите нормальную разметку "руками", не нужно "рисовать контролы мышкой", активно используйте штатные панели WPF.

Например, сделайте нормальную табличную верстку:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Control">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,2.5,0,2.5"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="80"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}"/>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}"/>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}"/>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Ваш пол:" FontSize="15"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1">
        <ComboBoxItem>Муж</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Жен</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Стиль:" FontSize="15"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <ComboBoxItem>Кроль</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Брасс</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Спина</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Баттерфляй</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Комплекс</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Мин:"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="Сек:"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Text="Мил. сек:"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Узнать"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это дизайнер маргинами контролы расставляет? Ни разу им не пользовался :)

Comment: Именно, если рисовать контролы мышкой, то они позиционируются с помощью Margin :)

Comment: Спасибо. Полезно знать и дальше им не пользоваться :)